# Connect bars with lines in R plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to connect the stacked bars with lines.

Expectation :

[image]

However I am unable to draw the lines between the bars. Have tried with the following script however it is not adding the line.

Using `add_trace` instead of 'add_lines' is not working.

```
df = data.frame(Aria = 20:25, Acqua = 21:26, Fuoco = 22:27, 
                Terra = 23:28, Cielo = 24:29, 
                Labels = c( 'Antonio', 'Maria', 'Giovanni',
                            'Sergio', 'Giorgio', 'Michele' ) )

evo_bar_plot_variant = function(plot_data, var_x, x_name = 'X axis', 
                                y_name = 'Y axis', ... ){
  df = data.frame(plot_data) 
  df = na.omit(df)
  var = quos(...) 
  names_vars = names( var )
  y_vars = names_vars[ startsWith( names_vars, 'var_y' ) ]
  y_var_names = sapply(1:length(y_vars), function(j){ 
                          quo_name(var[[y_vars[j]]] )})
  row_sum = df %>% 
              select( y_var_names ) %>% 
              rowSums()
  xenc = enquo( var_x )
  cols = colorRampPalette(c("white", "#4C68A2"))( length( y_vars ) )

  #... Plot parameters .....
  font_size = list( size = 12, family = 'Lato' )
  gray_axis = '#dadada'
  p = plot_ly(data = df, x = xenc, y = var[[ y_vars[1] ]], 
              name = quo_name( var[[ y_vars[1] ]] ), 
              type = 'bar', marker = list( color = cols[1], 
              line = list( color = '#E1E1E1', width = 0.8 ) ), 
              hoverlabel = list( font = font_size ) ) %>%
    layout(title = list( text = 'Bar', x = 0 ), barmode = 'stack',
           yaxis = list( title = y_name, showgrid = F, 
           zerolinecolor = gray_axis,
           titlefont = font_size, side = 'right' ),
           xaxis = list(title = x_name, linecolor = gray_axis,
                        zerolinecolor = gray_axis,
                        tickfont = font_size, titlefont = font_size),
           legend = list(font = font_size, orientation= 'h', 
                         font = font_size, x = 1 , y = 1.2, 
                         xanchor = "left", yanchor = 'top' ))

  if( length( y_vars ) >= 2 ){
    for( i in 2:length( y_vars ) ){
      p = p %>% 
            add_trace(y = var[[ y_vars[i] ]], 
                      name = quo_name( var[[ y_vars[i] ]] ), 
                      marker = list(color = cols[i], 
                      line = list(color = '#E1E1E1', width = 0.8)), 
                      hoverlabel = list(font = font_size))
    }
  }

  p =  p %>% 
        add_annotations(xref = 'x', yref = 'y', 
                        y = ( row_sum ) + 5, x = xenc,
                        text = paste( row_sum ), 
                        font = font_size, showarrow = F )

  p      
}

evo_bar_plot_variant( df, var_x = Labels, var_y1 = Aria, var_y2 = Acqua, var_y3 = Fuoco, var_y4 = Terra,
              var_y5 = Cielo )
```

Getting output like this :

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, I dropped a few lines of your example, as it isn't really minimal. Furthermore, I switched from `dplyr` to `data.table` as I'm more familar with it and melting the table makes thing much easier.

However, I hope the following is still helpful to you:

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

DF = data.frame(
  Aria = 20:25,
  Acqua = 21:26,
  Fuoco = 22:27,
  Terra = 23:28,
  Cielo = 24:29,
  Labels = c('Antonio', 'Maria', 'Giovanni',
             'Sergio', 'Giorgio', 'Michele')
)

setDT(DF)

DT <- melt.data.table(DF, id.vars = "Labels")
DT[, c("label_group", "cumsum_by_label") := .(.GRP, cumsum(value)), by = Labels]

lineDT <- rbindlist(list(DT[, .(
  label_group = label_group - 0.4,
  cumsum_by_label = cumsum_by_label,
  variable = variable
)],
DT[, .(
  label_group = label_group + 0.4,
  cumsum_by_label = cumsum_by_label,
  variable = variable
)]))

p <- plot_ly(
  DT,
  x = ~ label_group,
  y = ~ value,
  color = ~ variable,
  type = "bar",
  colors = ~ colorRampPalette(c("white", "#4C68A2"))(length(unique(variable)) + 1)[-1],
  legendgroup =  ~ variable,
  showlegend = TRUE
) %>%
  layout(
    title = list(text = 'Bar', x = 0),
    barmode = 'stack',
    legend = list(itemclick = FALSE, itemdoubleclick = FALSE)
  ) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      title = "X axis",
      ticktext = ~ Labels,
      tickvals = ~ label_group,
      tickmode = "array"
    ),
    yaxis = list(title = "")
  ) %>%
  add_annotations(
    text = ~ value,
    xref = 'x',
    yref = 'y',
    y = ~ cumsum_by_label - value / 2,
    x = ~ label_group,
    showarrow = FALSE
  ) %>%
  add_annotations(
    data = DT[, .(maxval = max(cumsum_by_label),
                  label_group = unique(label_group)), by = Labels],
    inherit = FALSE,
    text = ~ maxval,
    xref = 'x',
    yref = 'y',
    y = ~ maxval,
    x = ~ label_group,
    showarrow = FALSE,
    yshift = 20
  ) %>%
  add_lines(
    data = lineDT,
    inherit = FALSE,
    x = ~ c(label_group),
    y = ~ cumsum_by_label,
    color = ~ variable,
    legendgroup =  ~ variable,
    showlegend = FALSE,
    hoverinfo = "none"
  )

p
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I've been workiing with what turned out to be a sub-optimal solution for quite some time now. I just wanted to say that this approach is pretty impressive in all its simple beauty.

Comment: Thanks! What I'm not really happy with is the trace deselection on the legend (the lines might get misaligned when deselecting some of the traces, since the bar stacking works dynamically). Might be better to hide the legend.

Comment: Try adding `legend = list(itemclick = FALSE, itemdoubleclick = FALSE)` to your layout definition. This will allow the legend to remain but eliminate the issue with dynamic stacking by preventing the bars from being hidden/shown with by interacting with the legend. [See Plotly R Reference: layout-legend-itemclick](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-legend-itemclick)

Comment: @MattSummersgill thanks for the hint! Added `legend = list(itemclick = FALSE, itemdoubleclick = FALSE)` to the layout.

Comment: Moreover, added `hoverinfo="none"` for the lines, as they were misleading.

Comment: This is almost complete. Can you please add the sum and within cell numbers please ?

Comment: @SoumyaBoral added the annotations - please check my edit.